# spring @Transactional for sql procedure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a java method **saveAndCalculate(Person p)**, in which object **p** will firstly be persisted by hibernate via **saveOrUpdate** method. Then in the same method, a supplementary calculation will be done by executing a PL/SQL procedure and this procedure need the **p** is really written to the database. Since PL/SQL procedure can only be called in unchained transactions, I should annotate the method **saveAndCalculate** with **@Transactional(propagation=NEVER**. however how can I force the hibernate method **saveOrUpdate** been committed ?

Comment: I believe *unchained* is a Sybase thing, and *PL/SQL* is an Oracle thing, so are you sure you need to do any special *transaction* thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute session.flush() after session.saveOrUpdate to force hibernate to execute the update or insert on your database. In this case data changes will be applied to your database so your stored proc should be able to see the data.

Comment: There're this no method **flush** for **Session** class